# In Angular and Bootstrap, how do I click the button inside the expanded dropdown when hovering over the navigation item?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5, angular17

Current Behavior: When hovering over a navigation item, the dropdown container becomes visible, but it is not possible to click the button inside the container.

Expected Behavior: When hovering over a navigation item, the dropdown container should allow clicking the button inside. Additionally, when hovering outside the navigation item and dropdown container, the container should be hidden.

Here is the stackblitz code [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zrdejc?file=src%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.ts)

Html:

```
 <div class="flex-container">
  <div *ngFor="let item of navigations">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.type == 'dropdown'">
      <div
        class="dropdown p-0"
        (mouseenter)="showDropdown(item)"
        (mouseleave)="hideDropdown(item)"
      >
        <a
          class="cs-link-white dropdown-toggle"
          href="#"
          role="button"
          data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >
          {{ item.menuTitle }}
        </a>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.type == 'link'">
      <div>
        <a class="cs-link-white" href="#">{{ item.menuTitle }}</a>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
<div
  *ngIf="activeMenu"
  style="height: 200px; width: 100%; background-color: #c8c8c8;"
  class="dropdown-menu"
  [class.show]="isDropdownOpen[activeMenu.menuCode]"
>
  <div>
    Hello from {{ activeMenu.menuCode }}
    <button (click)="triggerAction()">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  background-color: #2f333a;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.cs-link-white {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  min-height: 44px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

ts:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface NavigationItem {
  menuTitle: string;
  menuCode: string;
  type: 'dropdown' | 'link';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class NavigationComponent {
  activeMenu!: NavigationItem;

  isDropdownOpen: any = {
    dropdown1: false,
    dropdown2: false,
    dropdown3: false,
  };

  navigations: NavigationItem[] = [
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 1',
      menuCode: 'dropdown1',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 2',
      menuCode: 'dropdown2',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 3',
      menuCode: 'dropdown3',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Link1',
      menuCode: 'link1',
      type: 'link',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Link2',
      menuCode: 'link2',
      type: 'link',
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

  showDropdown(item: NavigationItem) {
    this.activeMenu = item;
    this.isDropdownOpen[item.menuCode] = true;
  }

  hideDropdown(item: NavigationItem) {
    this.activeMenu = item;
    this.isDropdownOpen[item.menuCode] = false;
  }

  triggerAction() {
    console.log('button clicked');
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a `setTimeout` to wait for the hover to happen over the dropdown and then toggle the flag using the same mouseover events!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface NavigationItem {
  menuTitle: string;
  menuCode: string;
  type: 'dropdown' | 'link';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class NavigationComponent {
  activeMenu: NavigationItem = {
    menuTitle: 'Dropdown 1',
    menuCode: 'dropdown1',
    type: 'dropdown',
  };

  isDropdownOpen: any = {
    our_products: false,
    home_kitchen: false,
    toys: false,
    dropdown2: false,
    dropdown3: false,
  };

  navigations: NavigationItem[] = [
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 1',
      menuCode: 'dropdown1',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 2',
      menuCode: 'dropdown2',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 3',
      menuCode: 'dropdown3',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 4',
      menuCode: 'dropdown4',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 5',
      menuCode: 'dropdown5',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Dropdown 6',
      menuCode: 'dropdown6',
      type: 'dropdown',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Link1',
      menuCode: 'link1',
      type: 'link',
    },
    {
      menuTitle: 'Link2',
      menuCode: 'link2',
      type: 'link',
    },
  ];

  isDropdownOpenv1 = false;

  constructor() {}

  showDropdown(item: NavigationItem) {
    this.activeMenu = item;
    this.isDropdownOpen[item.menuCode] = true;
  }

  hideDropdown(event: any, item: NavigationItem) {
    console.log(event);
    const relatedTarget = event?.relatedTarget;
    if (relatedTarget?.classList.contains('dropdown-menu')) {
      return;
    }
    this.activeMenu = item;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isDropdownOpen[item.menuCode] = false;
    });
  }

  isMobileView(): boolean {
    return window.innerWidth < 992;
  }

  showDropdownv1() {
    this.isDropdownOpenv1 = true;
  }

  hideDropdownv1() {
    this.isDropdownOpenv1 = false;
  }

  triggerAction() {
    this.isDropdownOpen[this.activeMenu.menuCode] = false;
    console.log('button clicked');
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xqprje?file=src%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.html,src%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Naren, the functionality is as expected. However, when clicking the button, the dropdown does not close. It should behave similarly to a Bootstrap dropdown, where clicking any button in the dropdown automatically collapses it.

Comment: @VijaiS updated my answer, we need to toggle the flag through the code!

Comment: @VijaiS did the updated answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse your existing methods of show and hide dropdown. Just **add mouse enter and mouse leave events** to your **dropdown menu element** to make it work as expected.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dzkbth?file=src%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.html)

```html
<div
  *ngIf="activeMenu"
  (mouseenter)="showDropdown(activeMenu)"
  (mouseleave)="hideDropdown(activeMenu)"
  style="height: 200px; width: 100%; background-color: #c8c8c8;"
  class="dropdown-menu"
  [class.show]="isDropdownOpen[activeMenu.menuCode]"
>
  <div>
    Hello from {{ activeMenu.menuCode }}
    <button (click)="triggerAction()">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```